# Makes the prequarterfinals

Tags: usage

Is the following sentence correct?

> Makes in pre-quarterfinals; Ashwini & Sikki get a walkover in their opening match

Here is the [context](https://www.thehindu.com/sport/other-sports/world-badminton-championships-prannoy-stuns-lin-dan/article29184205.ece?homepage=true).

I think it should be

> Makes the pre quaterfinals

Answer (score -1):

"Makes the pre-quarterfinals" certainly looks much better. The hyphen that they used in the original article is perfectly fine (as Edward Barnard has pointed out in the comments), but "makes in" does look a lot more awkward than "makes the".

It is very possible that the author of the article made a mistake, since articles about new events are often written on a very tight deadline.

It is also possible (but less likely) that the author is talking about "makes" that are occurring in the pre-quarterfinals. Unfortunately this was just a "point-form" fragment rather than a full sentence, so we will never know.

But in general, you are right that "makes the pre-quarterfinals" sounds much better.

Comment: The semi-colon is a clue; it leads into what Ashwini & Sikki did. Here "makes" is a curious noun. "The makes in the pre QF were Ashwini & Sikki." Especially as **makes** is the wrong conjugation to be a verb.

Answer (score -1):

In American English, the quarterfinals are the third-to-last round of a single-elimination tournament.  Most team sports have two teams oppose each other in each match, with one winner and one loser.  Before the quarterfinals, there are 8 teams remaining in the tournament.  After the quarterfinals, there are 4 teams remaining.

If there are no byes, the round before the quarterfinals is called the "Round of 16".  In America's National Collegiate Athletic Association (NCAA) championship tournaments, the "Round of 16" is called the "Sweet 16".

In America's National Football League (NFL), there are many byes in the round before the quarterfinals.  The NFL has special names for each round of its playoff tournament.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the grammatical (or ungrammatical) nature of the phrase before the semicolon in the original sentence. It actually seems to be a non sequitur.

Comment: @JasonBassford -- "pre-quarterfinals" is incorrect in American English.  Therefore, "Makes the pre-quarterfinals" would still be incorrect in American English.  Are you aware of a dialect in which "pre-quarterfinals" is correct?

Comment: Which, again, is irrelevant to the question. If the sentence had started *makes in quarterfinals*, it would be just as wrong for the same reason—because *makes in X* is wrong, no matter, in this context, what *X* happens to be. Trying to argue for a particular *word* is overlooking the bigger issue with the construction of the phrase and the preposition. (And, that aside, although it's still not relevant, I disagree that *pre-quarterfinals* is incorrect. It's certainly uncommon, but It's a valid use of a prefix applied to a base word.)